# Seprated location block for same URI by different query-string Nginx

Tags: nginx, cache

These are my URIs

```
/posts.php?action=get_single_posts
/posts.php?action=search

/posts.php?action=get_all_posts
```

I need 2 separated location block for these URIs in Nginx because I want to cache first one and not cache the second one.
How can I do that?

**Additional**: Also have question about "**get_all_posts**" request. Users are ganna fetch this URL. Each of them has  unique "user_id" in their headers. Also each user should be able to get data based on his user_id (only get posts if this user_id is the owner of the post). 
Example:

```
User by user_id 10   should get posts A,B
User by user_id 11   should get posts C,D
```

If I pass them to upstream, they will get different data based on their user_id and is correct. I want to cache their response individually based on their headers['user_id'] field for request **"/posts.php?action=get_all_posts"**. If I cache this request universally, every user will get same data and its not right on this case.
How can I do that?

Comment: Or use the same `location` but set `expires` using a `map`. See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/939099/nginx-image-display-issue-after-optimization/939119#939119)

Comment: @RichardSmith nice its cool solution. I also added Additional question could you please check that out?